# Access a single value from a data frame in C++

Tags: c++, r, dataframe

I'm looking for a C++ function to access a single value from a data frame (SEXP object). So, if we let `df` be the R data frame, I'm looking for the C++ equivalent of `df[x,y]`.

Comment: Have you looked at [Rcpp](http://www.rcpp.org/) at all yet?  Pretty much anything and everything R and C++ related goes through it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That example is provided, *inter alia* by the [RcppExamples](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/rcppexamples/blob/master/src/DataFrameExample.cpp#L34_) package:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
List DataFrameExample(const DataFrame & DF) {

    // access each column by name
    IntegerVector a = DF["a"];
    CharacterVector b = DF["b"];
    DateVector c = DF["c"];

    // do something
    a[2] = 42;
    b[1] = "foo";
    c[0] = c[0] + 7; // move up a week

    // create a new data frame
    DataFrame NDF = DataFrame::create(Named("a")=a,
                                      Named("b")=b,
                                      Named("c")=c);

    // and return old and new in list
    return List::create(Named("origDataFrame") = DF,
                        Named("newDataFrame") = NDF);
}
```